# Bricked my Infocus m320u

Tags: rom-flashing

I am stuck with a logo and my phone doesn't boot. I can get its recovery mode but I couldn't find the suitable file for my phone to flash. Fastboot mode doesn't work.now how can I get fixed my mobile

Comment: But you didn't tell how you bricked it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting to the factory from the recovery menu. If it doesn't fix the issue, try flashing the ROM from recovery.

Download the  file from [here](https://www.needrom.com/download/infocus-m320u/), then boot to recovery select `firmware update`. (instructions also available from the download page).

If the above doesn't solve your issue, try flashing the phone using ba computer.

- Go to [this page](http://flashtool.org/3/download-infocus-firmware.html) and download the firmware file for your model.
- Go [here](https://spflashtool.com/) and download SP Flashtool.
- You may also need USB drivers, grab it in the first link (scroll down the page).